# failed to satisfy constraint: Specified resource is not reachable in this region ('us-east-1') - aws quicksight -

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

Using the nodejs AWS SDK i'm trying to update my quickSight DataSet with a csv file in S3 bucket. When calling the AWS quicksight update-data-set command(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/update-data-set.html) I'm getting the following error:

'physicalTableMap.string.member.s3Source.dataSourceArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Specified resource is not reachable in this region ('us-east-1')

I checked my quicksight region and s3 bucket region all set to 'us-east-1', so not sure why it's still complaining about region? IAM is also set to us-east-1

the dataSourceArn i'm passing is the arn for the S3 csv file.

```
   const updateDataSetParams: UpdateDataSetRequest = {
         AwsAccountId: awsAccountId /* required */,
         DataSetId: getEnvironmentKeyValue("AWS_PERMISSIONS_DATA_SET_ID") /* required */,
        ImportMode: "SPICE" /* required */,
         Name: getEnvironmentKeyValue("AWS_PERMISSIONS_DATA_SET_DISPLAY_NAME") /* required */,
         PhysicalTableMap: {
         string: {
           S3Source: {
            DataSourceArn: getEnvironmentKeyValue("AWS_PERMISSIONS_S3_DATA_SOURCE_ARN") /* required */,
            InputColumns: [
           /* required */
           {
              Name: "UserName" /* required */,
             Type: "STRING" /* required */
           },
           {
             Name: "CompanyName" /* required */,
            Type: "STRING" /* required */
           },
           {
             Name: "BranchIds" /* required */,
            Type: "STRING" /* required */
           }
          /* more items */
        ],
    UploadSettings: {
      ContainsHeader: true,
      Delimiter: ",",
      Format: "CSV"
      //      StartFromRow: 2
    }
  }
}
}
};

  const updateDataSet = await quicksight.updateDataSetAsync(updateDataSetParams);
```

p:s , I manage to call other quicksight commands like create-namespace and create-user which all work fine. Only when I try to update the dataset.

Comment: Have a look at these articles: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/troubleshoot-connect-S3.html, https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/quicksight-deny-policy-allow-bucket/

Comment: Hi, Yeah I followed the article and tried granting access to my userId, and role Id  only in the bucket policy, but still no luck. I even made the bucket have public access, still no luck. My IAM user has access to all s3 and quicksight actions. and Quicksight has access to S3 setted in Quicksight security section

Answer (score 1):

I found the error message `Specified resource is not reachable in this region` to be incredibly misleading. The same message was generated regardless of what `DataSourceArn` I supplied.

The solution in my case was to create the data set using the AWS console and then print the definitions using the CLI, which is what I used in my code.

Note that creating a data set using the console actually creates:

1. A data source + permissions
2. A data set + permissions

So I believe you are required to recreate the equivalent in code.

My working code is shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/adamcbuckley/05ac4e4115b483024532e6f44e6da1a7).  It is somewhat verbose, and I doubt that every config parameter is actually required.  My source data is in JSON format, but to be honest I think that CSV would be much less confusing.

The following sample CLI commands will help you get the data from QuickSight to paste into your code.

List data sources

```
aws quicksight list-data-sources --aws-account-id 111111111111
```

Describe data source

```
aws quicksight describe-data-source --aws-account-id 111111111111 --data-source-id "b64cc8ac-e85d-4116-b4dc-cf901b530046"
```

Describe data source permissions

```
aws quicksight describe-data-source-permissions --aws-account-id 111111111111 --data-source-id "b64cc8ac-e85d-4116-b4dc-cf901b530046"
```

List data sets

```
aws quicksight list-data-sets --aws-account-id 111111111111
```

Describe data set

```
aws quicksight describe-data-set --aws-account-id 111111111111 --data-set-id "a2ea12e6-2583-4930-a492-b4797bf37ab4"
```

Describe data set permissions

```
aws quicksight describe-data-set-permissions --aws-account-id 111111111111 --data-set-id "a2ea12e6-2583-4930-a492-b4797bf37ab4"
```

Comment: Absolute lifesaver my man, thanks so much